# Converting vpnc conf to OpenConnect

Tags: cisco-vpn, vpn-client, openconnect

I have this vpnc config file

```
IPSec gateway my_srv.com
IPSec ID aaaaa
IPSec secret bbbbbb
Xauth username ccccc
Xauth password dddddd
Enable Single DES
```

How can I convert it to be compatible with "openconnect"
(I tried vpnc-script but failed with "this script must be called from vpnc !?? )